# How to dualboot Gentoo with void?

Tags: filesystems

I have a laptop with dual storage. `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`

`/dev/sda1` is the UEFI boot partition that I created during Gentoo's installation

`/dev/sda2` is where Gentoo is installed..ext4

I have partitioned `/dev/sdb` into one partition `/dev/sdb1` `ext4` mounted at `/`

Now I want to install void on `/dev/sdb1` and dualboot it with Gentoo (both Gentoo and Void showing on GRUB's screen at boot)

My understanding is that, all I have to do to dualboot is to choose `/dev/sda` when I get to the "select the disk to install the bootloader" page during void's installation ?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar plans and was satisfied with these instructions:

> **Select the disk** to install a bootloader on when Void is installed. You
> may select **none** to skip this step and install a bootloader manually
> after completing the installation process.

because at the end it says:

> ... [The installer] will then generate an initramfs and **install a
> GRUB2 bootloader** to the bootable partition.

So I would leave the running whole `sda` disk untouched - if you choose `void`, and void offers you `none` as target, why insist on automatic sda?

---

Copy kernel and initramfs to the ESP (sda1) and make a second boot entry is all you have to do. I boot from UEFI shell, so I can manually start the new kernel-initrams pair with the options needed and wanted (root=,... ), and/or save it in a one-line file on the ESP. With Grub this is also just a matter of adding a line - actually you should be able to enter a manual KCL in grub, too.

---

> *I have partitioned /dev/sdb into one partition /dev/sdb1 ext4 mounted
> at /*

But after booting the installer nothing is mounted, and the names sd[ab] are not how you identify disks in early boot (before a/the kernel itself has booted).

---

Why not invest in a 1-2GB ESP also on the "second" disk? This could be useful once the second disk has to boot up alone.